# Codename One MultiButton - two action buttons in one textline

Tags: java, material-design, codenameone

In Codename One I'm trying to achieve a user card with some description and two action buttons(Call and SMS) at the bottom of the card horizontally to each other. Is there a way to "split" the last textLine? Help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: A `MultiButton` is a lead component. You shouldn't add components into it or invoke container operations on it. You should construct a UI as Diamond suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the 2 buttons in a TableLayout, GridLayout or FlowLayout container... and place this container at the botton of your user card container.

```
Container actionCont = TableLayout.enclose(2, btnCall, btnSMS);
userCardContainer.add(actionCont);
```